# how to log the request coming from the client in spring

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets

I want to log the json data which is posted from the client. I have written the interceptor also. I am receiving request but I am unable to log the json part of the reuqest. How can I do it?
here is my postdata json:

```
{"callerId":3456,"sessionId":"1554ba7c-b729-4dc5-9dd2-c48e2b275c3f","uniqueId":"some","courseProgress":{"bookmark":{"contentId":"aec4b2c5-6766-4d51-80ac-8fdc61f465ed","version":1}}}
```

here is my loggerInterceptor code :

```
 public class LoggerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggerInterceptor.class);

    static {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
    }

    @Override

public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                         HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

    logger.info("Before handling the request");

    return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
}
}
```

So I am getting the request but not able to retreive the json data

Comment: A `HandlerInterceptor` is not ideal for this. Use a `Filter` where you can wrap the `HttpServletRequest`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis : can u help me in this as I am new to spring